# Explain some javascript/jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've encountered code below and I'm not fully sure what it's achieving.

I think it invokes the service 'getvalues' and passes some data into the service. On success the data returned is processed. Is this correct ?

```
 $.ajax({
      url: 'getvalues',
      data: ({urlVal : value}),
      success: function(data) {           
      }
    });
```

Comment: Read this http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: is this a lecture or an inquiry? i see no question.

Comment: Correct. Read more at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax

Comment: jQuery has a pretty good API. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Why all the downvotes, this is a valid question.

Comment: Because it is a valid question that could be answered with just a little research

Comment: "Why all the downvotes" Because the docs explain it as linked by multiple people and people probably think you did not put the effort into researching before asking.

Comment: Many answered questions are explained by their docs. '$.ajax' does not return anything valid within google. I'll know where to look in future, but dont think it should have costed 14 reputation. Just because a question is easy for some people does not mean its easy for everyone.

Comment: @user470184 better read on [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). It's not a matter of "easiness for each one of us", it's about showing some effort.

Comment: I did show some effort, I made an attempt at answering the question myself, and was just looking for verification I was on the right path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try asking google?

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> url:
>
> A string containing the URL to which the request is sent.
>
> data:
>
> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if
>   not already a string.
>
> success(data, textStatus, jqXHR):
>
> A function to be called if the request succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

calls the getvalues url and passes the parameters urlVal to that page, then it gets the returns data from getvalues, but does not output it.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly.

It makes a GET request to 'getvalues' url (relative to current page),
sending value of `value` variable as `urlVal` parameter,
and on success it does nothing (empty function).

Comment: $.ajax makes a GET request by default, not POST.